# Counteract a javascript redirect?

Tags: javascript

I am loading an external page in an iFrame that redirects after a counter. I want to disable the redirect.I used firebug to locate the redirect.

```
if(!counter)
  self.iframe.src=self.vars["someurl"];
```

So how do I stop this redirect from happening?

Thank you,    Todd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't control JavaScript that comes from a different domain (which is what I am assuming you are doing, when saying "external page").

If you think a bit about browser security, you will understand why.

See [Same Origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) on wikipedia for details.

Comment: That is exactly what I meant. Security issue makes sense. So there is no way to control the browser and not redirect?

Comment: @maddogandnoriko - Not really. The site owner implemented a frame buster for a reason... they don't want their site to appear in a frame.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe `counter = -1`?

I mean, typing `counter = -1` in Firebug before the counter goes to zero.

Comment: `window.counter` is set on a per document basis. The document loaded into the iframe is a different document.